# Integrating my ecommerce store with FB

Tags: facebook, e-commerce, integration, integrate

I have an ecommerce store and want to start the ball rolling on integrating it into FB. See here for an example of a local client that has done it: http://apps.facebook.com/woolworthsstore/fbHome.jsp

Is this an iframe? How do I go about setting this up?

Thanks,
Deon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is external content provided via an iframe. You are looking to setup a Facebook Page Tab App.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/